# How to go through array with button press

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I have an array that contains different information,

how can I iterate through the array with a button press? I have two buttons, and I need to allow one to move forward in the array and the back button to display the previous index.

```swift
  @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!



 @IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!



Let infoArray = ["info1","info2","info3","info4"] 

@IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender: Any) {
// Change the label based on the selected index in array        

}

@IBAction func backTapped(_ sender: Any) {
 //Return to previous index and update label text

}
```

I also added page control for better UX, but for now I'm just worried about learning how to even change the label through button Tap.

My guess would be to start the index at 0 which would be `info1` and go from there. I can worry about saving index state later.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "My guess would be to start the index at 0 which would be info1 and go from" And that would be right.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please check the below code you can do something like this to move your array forward and backward. Please add other checks according to your need.

```
var i = 0
let infoArray = ["info1","info2","info3","info4"]

@IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    // Change the label based on the selected index in array
   if i >= 0 && i < infoArray.count{
   dataLbl.text = infoArray[i]

    }
    if i > 3 {
        i = i-1
    } else  {
        i = i+1
    }

}

@IBAction func backTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    //Return to previous index and update label text
    if i >= 0 && i < infoArray.count-1 {
    dataLbl.text = infoArray[i]

    }
    if i < 0 {
        i = i+1
    } else  {
       i = i-1
    }

}
```

Comment: Although I can iterate through the array, the issue I have with this code is once you get to the final index it does not allow me to return to the previous index.

Comment: This answer is the is closest related to my question, I'll figure out the rest from here so I will accept, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The logic should look something like this

```
let infoArray = ["info1","info2","info3","info4"]

func viewDidLoad() {
    pageControl.numberOfPages = infoArray.count
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
}

@IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    // Change the label based on the selected index in array
    guard pageControl.currentPage + 1 < infoArray.count else {
        return
    }
    pageControl.currentPage += 1
}

@IBAction func backTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    //Return to previous index and update label text
    guard pageControl.currentPage - 1 >= 0 else {
        return
    }
    pageControl.currentPage -= 1
}
```

> When a user taps a page control to move to the next or previous page, the control sends the valueChanged event for handling by the delegate. The delegate can then evaluate the currentPage property to determine the page to display. The page control advances only one page in either direction.

Comment: great answer I can implement page control into the function. Thank you for your response, will thumbs up!